# MenuFlyout at center of page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, windows-10, uwp

In my UWP ,I'm trying to Open a MenuFlyout at center of Frame.

How can I place it at center?

I've tried this piece of code, but it set flyout at top of frame.

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender,ItemClickEventArgs e) {
    var m = new MenuFlyout();
    var t = new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "SomeTxt"};
    m.Items.Add(t);
    m.ShowAt((FrameworkElement)Frame);
}
```

Even tried to add `m.Placement = Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.FlyoutPlacementMode.Center;` but FlyoutPlacementMode enum doesn't contain `Center`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no `Center` value in `FlyoutPlacementMode` so you will need to write a bit more code for a workaround.

The idea is to first set `FlyoutPlacementMode` to `Full`, then instead of having the content stretching out to fill the entire page, we change the `Style` of the `MenuFlyoutPresenter` to make its content centered both horizontally and vertically.

So what I have done is I generated the following default style using Blend and placed it inside `Page.Resources`, and then I specified `HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"` on the root `Grid` in order to center the content in the middle.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CenteredMenuFlyoutPresenterStyle" TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutPresenterThemePadding}" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMinWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMaxWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource MenuFlyoutThemeMinHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutPresenter">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="MenuFlyoutPresenterScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <Border x:Name="MenuFlyoutPresenterBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then simply apply the style to the `MenuFlyout` like this -

```
var m = new MenuFlyout
{
    Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Full,
    MenuFlyoutPresenterStyle = (Style)this.Resources["CenteredMenuFlyoutPresenterStyle"]
};

var t = new MenuFlyoutItem() { Text = "SomeTxt" };
m.Items.Add(t);
m.ShowAt((FrameworkElement)sender);
```